# Getting data after Specific date and hour, but Date and Hour are in diffferent columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble in getting data after a delimiter date and hour in this table named Test:

Columns and sample data:

| id | Date | Hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20091220 | 23:10:23 |
| 2 | 20201020 | 10:10:25 |
| 3 | 20101020 | 15:10:27 |

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE Date > 20090101
  AND Hour > '15:22:33'
```

and:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM test 
     WHERE Date >= 20090101) AS a
WHERE a.Hour>= '15:22:33'
```

However both queries returned this result:

| id | Date | Hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20091220 | 23:10:23 |

when the expected result was **all the lines as all data is after 2009/01/01**. I understand that the issue is the Hour delimiter however I can't work my way around that

I am currently using SQL Server Management Studio v18

Comment: The better answer is to convert the 'date' and 'hour' to datetime and then add them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably better to store the date time in a *single* column.  But I think the logic you want is:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE Date > 20090102 OR
      (Date = 20090102 AND Hour > '15:22:33')
```

This returns all rows where the date is after 20090102 15:22:343.

Or, you can phrase this as:

```
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, CONCAT(date, ' ', hour)) > '2009-01-02 15:22:33'
```

This version actually suggests a modification to the table using a computed column:

```
alter table test add column date_hour as
    ( CONVERT(datetime, CONCAT(date, ' ', hour)) );
```

Then you can write:

```
where date_hour > '2009-01-02 15:22:33'
```

And you can create an index on the `date_hour` column to improve performance.

Comment: Depending on the language, this could be a problem. `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` is *not* unambiguous (for the `datetime` datatype). In fact, unless you're American, the date would be read as `yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss`. For example, if you're English (who, according to Microsoft don't speak English???) the above would error (if we ignore that the syntax is actually `ADD` not `ADD COLUMN`). [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4324f070ad520e01a833af76a49e5a0a)

Comment: It worked! Thank you!!
I understand it would be beter to store these in a single column but this data comes from an ERP and there's not much I can do about it. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: the "Date" column is not an datetime but an int, so it works when we use YYYYMMDD as Gordon suggested as the most significant value is to the left, kinda messy but there's nothing I can do since it's a client's ERP

Comment: Then you *really* need to fix the design. An `int` isn't a date, @thiagopleasehelp , and a `date` isn't a number. A column defined as `date int` makes no sense; it is, by definition, *not* a date...

Comment: As I said, that's from a client's database (a very big company from Brazil actually), I'm only developing stuff for them as a tercerized employee, the stuff you find in Brazilian databases will always surprise you (in a good or bad way hahaha), for them, as long as it works, it's fine. But I do agree with you